# Discord.py Automatically assign roles to users having specific keywords in a message or image

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm extremely new to discord.py and I was wondering if there is an existing bot or if I could make a bot that can assign a role to a user based on keywords in a text and/or image to get a specific role through verification.

Is this possible and if so can I get some help with it?

I have tried looking for bots that may have this feature but I have been unsuccessful, I am somewhat willing to make a bot as well but I'm a beginner coder but I am willing to figure things out!

Comment: _Theoretically_, it is probably possible. What exactly do you need help with? Any existing code?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. But I'm unsure when you want this to be triggered;

- checking every possible message?
- messages in a certain channel?
- some kind of response to a slash command/modal dialog?
- etc

Let's role with "checking every possible message" for a basic example.

Let's say we have a server about people's favourite fruit and we want to assign users a role based on their favourite fruit as this gives them access to the private channel about that fruit.

```py
import discord

# we have already created roles in our server for the fruits
# so we'll put the IDs here for ease of use
ROLES = {
    "banana": 112233445566,
    "apple": 123456123456,
    "orange": 665544332211
}

# requires elevated privileges - but let's say we've ticked those
intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = discord.Bot(intents=intents)

# register a client event to trigger some code every time a message is sent
@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    message_content = message.content.lower()

    if "bananas are good" in message_content:
        role = ROLES["banana"]
    elif "apples are good" in message_content:
        role = ROLES["apple"]
    elif "oranges are good" in message_content:
        role = ROLES["orange"]
    else:
        # make sure we have a case for when nothing we want is found
        role = None
    
    if not role:
        # exit out if we don't have a role to assign
        return
    
    guild_roles = await message.guild.fetch_roles()
    our_role = [gr for gr in guild_roles if gr.id == role]
    await message.author.add_roles(our_role)


client.run(OUR_TOKEN)
```

This is a *very basic* example but it possible. Ideally, we'd have a better way of checking message content - either via regex or other form of analysis. Additionally, we'd probably only check messages in a certain channel (or another method entirely, like a modal dialogue or a slash command). Also, what we're not doing above, is removing the user from the other roles (provided you would want that). So it would be possible for a user to have the "banana", "oranges", and "apples" roles all at once.

Hopefully that gives some ideas of where to start. Images would be similar - triggering some kind of function when you want it, downloading the image and running whatever analysis you want on the image.

**Disclaimer**: I wrote this with the `pycord` library in mind and didn't see the `discord.py` tag - should mostly be similar though but might not be.